# IOS: opengles and EXC_RESOURCE WAKEUPS

Tags: ios, multithreading, ios8

My Team was having some problems with the Wakeups per second (from here w/s) limit in the Main thread. When we analyzed, how many wakeups where caused by what, we found around 100 w/s that were unacounted for.

After stripping our library element by element we found out, that Apples OpenGLES framework is the problem. Just linking the framework to an empty App leads to 100 w/s in the main thread.

Does anybody have experience with this problem? Is it possible to configure the framework in a way, that takes less of this now precious resource?